# How do I predict what the users input will be in an HTML form using Python and Django?

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, autocomplete

On my website I have a text input field where Rick Ross method equals post and I want to find out how I can predict or autocomplete the form as the user is typing so they may be able to select something that already exists. My method up to this point was to try and use JavaScript with an integration with Django and python code in the HTML form. It looked like the following.

```
var all{ {% for i in items %}
        {{ i }},
        {% endfor %}
}
```

With JavaScript. I'm sorry I don't have it handy right now. Is there an easy way to go about completing this text field or popping up suggestions while the user is typing?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of JavaScript autocomplete libraries.

Comment: All of which I have no clue on how to use. I'm a beginner at this and I need someone to provide me with a specific method that is congruent with my code...

Comment: When Django God has spoken you have to listen @NickReardon! But for real, there are videos on youtube doing things step by step, explaining everything. Search for "Django autocomplete light". But Django isn't even required at all here. You can/should do that with simple JS. If you don't know how: read -> try -> fail ->try again ->learn

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good approach. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Please come up with more complex question. And put question with what you have done so far...

Comment: Ok will do asap